# Drop rows to keep consecutive duplicate values - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to drop rows where values in a specific column *are not* duplicated for at least 3 consecutive rows. Using the df below, I want to drop rows where consecutive values in `Code` are less than 3.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],  
    'ID' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'Code' : ['X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'X', 'X'],                  
    'X' : [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 6, 2, 1, 6, 7, 2, 7, 8, 1], 
    'Y' : [2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 5, 2, 2, 6, 5, 1, 5, 4, 1],                         
        })

m = (df["Code"].eq(df["Code"].shift()) | df["Code"].eq(df["Code"].shift(-3)))

print (df[m])
```

Intended Output:

```
    Time ID Code  X  Y
0      1  A    X  3  2
1      2  A    X  4  4
2      3  A    X  5  5
7      8  B    Y  2  2
8      9  B    Y  1  2
9     10  B    Y  6  6
10    11  C    Y  7  5
11    12  C    Y  2  1
12    13  C    X  7  5
13    14  C    X  8  4
14    15  C    X  1  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create consecutive groups by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) first:

```
s = df["Code"].ne(df["Code"].shift()).cumsum()
```

And then filtering by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = df[s.map(s.value_counts()).ge(3)]
```

Alternative solution with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = df[s.groupby(s).transform('size').ge(3)]
```

---

```
print (df)
    Time ID Code  X  Y
0      1  A    X  3  2
1      2  A    X  4  4
2      3  A    X  5  5
7      8  B    Y  2  2
8      9  B    Y  1  2
9     10  B    Y  6  6
10    11  C    Y  7  5
11    12  C    Y  2  1
12    13  C    X  7  5
13    14  C    X  8  4
14    15  C    X  1  1
```

Comment: The first option would be quicker?

Comment: Have u ever done some benchmark on size vs count? Just unsure of which is preferable

Comment: @yatu - I think 2 different functions, here working same, because never missing value, so not sure if generally compare (exclude, include NaNs)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom grouper identifying gruops of consecutive `Codes`, and use it to groupby and transform with the `count` of `Code`. Finally you want to keep those above or equal to 3:

```
g = df.Code.ne(df.Code.shift()).cumsum()
df[df.groupby(g).Code.transform('count').ge(3)]

    Time ID Code  X  Y
0      1  A    X  3  2
1      2  A    X  4  4
2      3  A    X  5  5
7      8  B    Y  2  2
8      9  B    Y  1  2
9     10  B    Y  6  6
10    11  C    Y  7  5
11    12  C    Y  2  1
12    13  C    X  7  5
13    14  C    X  8  4
14    15  C    X  1  1
```